# vscode extensions have low download/reviews count on linux but not on windows?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, archlinux

like the title says why, did i installed vscode wrong ? i "used pacman -S code" (not the aur vscode package), did some searching but did not find anything maybe i used the wrong key words maybe but anyway any answer will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you running VSCodium or VSCCode

Comment: "Official Arch Linux open-source release Ships a configuration enabling Open VSX." that info is from the arch wiki i thank it is not the vscode  also from the package description it says The Open Source build of Visual Studio Code (vscode) editor so i do not know as far is i know vscode is open source

Comment: VSCodium uses the OpenVSX extension storage, it is a separate build of VSC repo without the telemetry stuff and maybe other MS specials, on the VSC site you can find Linux versions